# String.Split Newlines in .Net CF

Tags: c#, string, compact-framework

Ive been trying to split strings in .NET CF but to no success.
If i would have a string like:

> Hello
>
> There
>
> World

Then I want each word to be stored in a string array so I can put them individually in my datagrid cell.

Unfortunately, this code I have doesnt seem to remove the New Lines:

```
string text = _scanResult; //Scan result contains the Hello There World string
string[] lines = text.Split(new Char[] {'\n','\r');
for (int x = 0; x < lines.Length; x++)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(lines[x]);
}
dataGrid1.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Environment.NewLine` instead, and use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`:

```
string[] lines = text.Split(new string[] {Environment.NewLine}, 
                            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: But .NET Compact Framework only supports Char[] not string[].

Comment: @jeraldov - Fair enough. The above will also work with `new Char[] {'\n','\r'}`.

Comment: You will end up with empty entries when using the '\n' and '\r' as separate characters. LINQ can exclude these entries (before converting .ToList) using something like `.Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))`

Answer (score 0):

Well, since only characters are accepted as a parameter in String.Split in .NET Compact Framework.

All I had to do was replace the new lines to "\n" character.

Here is the code for some people that might bump into the same problem in the future.

```
string text = stringWithNewLines;
text = text.Replace(Environment.NewLine,"\n");
string[] lines = text.Split(new Char[] { '\n' });
for (int x = 0; x < lines.Length; x++)
{  
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lines[x]))
    {
    dt.Rows.Add(lines[x]); //Add each string to datatable rows for use in datagrid
    }
 }
```

Comment: Vote to replace `lines[x] != ""` with `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lines[x])`

Comment: Edited. lines[x] != "" with !String.IsNullOrEmpty(lines[x])

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple version:

```
var _scanResult = "foo\r\nbar\r\n";

var lines = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(_scanResult, "\r\n")
            .Where(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l));
```