# StringSplitOptions does not exists in the context

Tags: c#, .net-cf-3.5

I am running my code in .NetCF and this line is showing error as

> StringSplitOptions does not exists in the context.

Please help what I am doing wrong.

```
string[] values = headerData.Split(new string[] { "<#Tag(", ")>"},  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Can I Fetch value1 value2 value3 from "<#Tag(value1)> <#Tag(value2> <#Tag(value3)>" and pass it to string[] without using StringSplitOptions

Comment: Maybe related thread: [WIndows Mobile 6 SDK - string.Split and StringSplitOptions - can't find](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31835127/)

Answer (score 11):

According to [this reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4b1f82b9-3b09-4d6b-8567-14ebf2d48ef1/stringsplitoptions-not-working?forum=netfxcompact), the .NET Compact Framework does not have `StringSplitOptions`.

Here is an alternative that uses [`Regex.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string[] values =
    Regex.Split(headerData, "<#Tag\\(|\\)>")
    .Where(x => x != string.Empty)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Then what should I replace my line of code in order to make it work

Comment: Couple of answers with alternatives in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310351/string-split-newlines-in-net-cf)

Comment: @ParthDesai, I updated my answer to include an alternative based on an answer of the question referenced in the comment above.

Comment: System array does not contain definition for where Error

Comment: @ParthDesai, make sure you import the `System.Linq` namespace via `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 1):

Write the namespace "System" at the beginning of the Enum like this:

```
string[] values = headerData.Split(new string[] { "<#Tag(", ")>"}, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

It didn't work in my application when I only used StringSplitOptions for some reason.

Comment: Thank you, this solution works better for my situation

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this overload is not supported in compact framework.
From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.90).aspx):

> **Version Information**
>   .NET Framework
>   Supported in: 3.5, 3.0, 2.0

as apposed to other split overloads such as [`String.Split Method (Char[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.90).aspx) where the documentation specifically mentions CF:

> Version Information
>   .NET Framework
>   Supported in: 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0
>   .NET Compact Framework
>   Supported in: 3.5, 2.0, 1.0
>   XNA Framework
>   Supported in: 3.0, 2.0, 1.0

Comment: Newer versions of the documentation write the "Version Information" in a more verbose format, for example [`StringSplitOptions` Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx) currently has: `Version Information -- Universal Windows Platform
Available since 4.5
.NET Framework
Available since 2.0
Portable Class Library
Supported in: portable .NET platforms
Silverlight
Available since 2.0
Windows Phone Silverlight
Available since 7.0
Windows Phone
Available since 8.1`

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: True, but this doesn't include .net compact framework. nor does portable .net platforms, note the [Target options part of the portable .net platforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx#platforms) page.

Comment: While your answer is correct, the other answer is better since it's actually provides a solution to the problem and not just the cause.

Comment: Yes. It appears that in the .NET 3.5 days (2007/2008), they had ".NET Compact Framework" in which the enum type `StringSplitOptions` was **not** supported. This is what the asker uses. Then since .NET 4.0 time (2010), they (no longer talk about "Compact Framework" and) have "Portable Class Library" which **does** support `StringSplitOptions`.